# How to create a Google gannt chart dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am using App Script to create a dashboard. I want to create a Gannt chart. I looked in the [docuentation here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#no-dependencies), and I have one problem. I don't know the size of my Gannt chart. Sometimes there will be 10 rows, sometimes 4. So I want to create it dynamically.

I succeeded in creating an HTML table dynamically, but I cannot create this Gannt chart dynamically.

I have a database to which I connect and I return a matrix with every row, start date, end date etc.
I am using scriptlets to call my functions like this:

```
<?  var miles = readMilestones(projectID);    
    for (var i = 0; i < miles.length; i++) {
    ?>
  data.addRow(
    [null, <?= miles[i].name?>, null,
     new Date(<?= miles[i].start ?>), new Date(<?= miles[i].end ?>), null, parseFloat(<?= miles[i].perc?>) * 100, null]);
  <? 
  }
  ?>
```

My problem is that this loop returns only the last row of my matrix.
I use the same loop to dynamically create a table and it works just fine. Here is the code for the table that works fine.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Milestone</td>
    <td>Start</td>
    <td>End</td>
    <td>%</td>
    </tr>      

    <?
    for (var i = 0; i < miles.length; i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?=i+1?></td>
    <td><?=miles[i].name?></td>
    <td><?=miles[i].start?></td>
    <td>        
    <?        
    if(miles[i].end == null){           
    ?>
    <?= '?' + miles[i].est_end?>
    <?
    }
    else {
    ?>
    <?=miles[i].end?>
    <?
    }
    ?>
    </td>

    <td style="<?=miles[i].color?>"><?=parseFloat(miles[i].perc) * 100 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>        
    </table>
```

Comment: not familiar with `appscript` but I don't see a problem with the loop, is there more you can share? such as a sample of the data or how it is obtained...?

Comment: I posted the solution. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find the problem. Apparently the first parameter cannot be null. I mean it can, but it returns only one row.

The solution is to put a value in the first parameter, which in my case was 'Task Id'. I put the current iterator.

```
<?
    for (var i = 0; i < mile.length; i++) {
    ?>
data.addRow(
    [<?=i?>, <?= mile[i].name?>, null,
     new Date(<?= mile[i].start ?>), new Date(<?= mile[i].end ?>), null, parseFloat(<?= mile[i].perc?>) * 100, null]
   );

   <? 
  }
  ?>
```